# Exception after upgrading to Uno.UI 3.9.7: FrameNavigationController is pushing the same view controller instance PageViewController more than once

Tags: ios, uno-platform

After updating to `Uno.UI 3.9.7` from `Uno.UI 3.4.0-dev.109` my application started crashing with an exception of:

```
<Uno_UI_Controls_NativeFramePresenter_FrameNavigationController: 0x117bcb400> is pushing the same view controller instance (<Uno_UI_Controls_NativeFramePresenter_PageViewController: 0x11998c8e0>) more than once which is not supported and is most likely an error in the application
```

I understand the concept of not being able to push the same view controller instance on iOS, but since this is Uno doing something, I am not completely sure on what's causing this. In the older version it works just fine.

I do have some logic that is navigating between a few pages in quick succession, could this be related to the issue?

Edit 1:
I found out that when I uncomment this code:

```
CurrentFrame.BackStack.Remove(CurrentFrame.BackStack.Last());
```

The exception does not occur anymore, but I lose the ability to erase pages from the backstack which I do not want the back navigation to return towards. Better understanding of the mechanics of the FrameNavigationController could help with resolving this.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Can you you open an issue with a repro? Looks like it's not something we've seen before.

Comment: @JérômeLaban: I'll get on it